# My Nepenthes Alata is growing leaves, but its tendrils are drying

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations, growth, carnivorous-plants

I bought a new pitcher plant (nepenthes alata) and since, it was doing great, there are no pitchers since I got it but it has shown significant growth...

I observed that its tendrils(which are supposed to produce pitchers) are drying...

How should I prevent this from happening and encourage growth of new pitchers?

Comment: Can you add a picture?